# OpenCV, Android: Detecting an object from an image instead of real-time detection

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, opencv

I am making an android application that can detect an object from an image frame captured from a video.

The sample applications in openCV only have examples on real-time detection.

Additional Info: 
-I'm using Haar classifier

As of now I'm storing the frames captured in an array of ImageView, how can i use OpenCV to detect the object and draw a rectangle around it?

```
for(int i=0 ;i <6; i++)
        {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(ids_of_images[i]);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(retriever.getFrameAtTime(looper,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC));
            Log.e("MicroSeconds: ", ""+looper);
            looper +=10000;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i hope you have integrated opencv 4 android library in your project . 
Now, you can convert image to Mat using opencv function

```
Mat srcMat = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(yourbitmap,srcMat);
```

Once, you have mat you can apply opencv functions to find rectangle objects from image. 
Now , follow the code to detect rectangle :

```
Mat mGray = new Mat();
cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 1);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mGray, mGray, new Size(3, 3), 5, 10, BORDER_DEFAULT);
Canny(mGray, mGray, otsu_thresold, otsu_thresold * 0.5, 3, true); // edge detection using canny edge detection algorithm
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
Imgproc.findContours(mGray,contours,hierarchy,Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Now , you have contours from image . So,you can get the max contour from it and draw it using drawContour() method :

```
for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++){
Imgproc.drawContours(src, contours, contourIdx, new Scalar(0, 0, 255)-1);
}
```

and you're done !! you can refer this link :
[Android using drawContours to fill region](http://answers.opencv.org/question/43700/android-using-drawcontours-to-fill-region/)

hope it will help !!